# Unit Testing node.js using jasmine unit testing framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to understand how to unit test node.js project but I am unsure why my current test is not working.

I have 2 files fed.js (src) and fed.spec.js (spec)

*This is the error I am getting when I run this...*

**Error:**

```
Snap should return 142
Expected undefined to be 142.
Error: Expected undefined to be 142.
```

**The Jist:**

I am trying to run a test to ensure that the variable *AllowanceAdditional* (located in fed.js) is equal to 142.

So I ran a jasmine unit test (located in fed.spec.js) and stated that I expected AllowanceAdditional to equal (==) or to be (===) 142. But The error I get returned is that AllowanceAdditional is undefined...

Can someone educate me or point me in the right direction, I don't understand why this is not working. What am I doing wrong? I hope my question makes sense, if not please tell me and I will further clarify

Comment: Sorry, added the additional information. I am expecting the variable AllowanceAdditional to return 142, but it says it returns "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

You must export it:

```
exports.AllowanceAdditional = 142;
```

In JavaScript, there are other ways to express this.

In my practice, I typically use:

```
function () {
    this.AllowanceAdditional = 142;
}.call(this);
```

The point is to attach your global variables and functions to the to the proper scope so Node.js can find them.

Inside the browser, since `.call(this)` will always pass in the `window` object. It gets attached to the global scope.

Comment: I am exporting it, I'm using module.exports = snap to export the whole snap object. My question is really more about how to make my test pass?

Comment: Do you mean I should add thie exports.AllowanceAdditional = 142; in the src file or the spec file?

Comment: The src file, node needs to be able to find it